# How to access the second of two entries for the same tag?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access the value inside a div with a class named 'lead-value'. This is the second such occurrence of a div with class with value 'lead-value', so I'm trying to access this particular instance by subsetting under the parent where the second 'lead-value' occurs.

Here is the html:

```
<td title="College Readiness is based on the percentages of 12th graders who were tested and passed AP&#174; exams. The maximum college readiness index value is 100.0." class="column-last column-even table-column-last table-column-even  g_school_in_country_college_readiness_index_stacked  cluetip">

                    <div>
    <p><div class="lead-value">100.0</div>
```

So I'd like to use the monster class name `"column-last column-even table-column-last table-column-even  g_school_in_country_college_readiness_index_stacked  cluetip"` to get the value, '100'.

How would I do this using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: If you are ok to switch to `lxml`, you can use a simple xpath expression `//div[@class="lead-value"][2]`.

Comment: Not ideal, but helpful! I'll look into the BS documentation regarding how BS supports lxml parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, the original example.html file is like:

```
<div class="lead-value">80.0</div>
<div class="lead-value">100.0</div>
<div class="lead-value">120.0</div>
<div class="lead-value">140.0</div>
```

The python code is:

```
>>>inf = open("example.html") 
>>>content = inf.read()
>>>inf.close()
>>>soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
>>>soup.findall('div',{'class':'lead-value'})
[<div class="lead-value">80.0</div>, <div class="lead-value">100.0</div>, <div class="lead-value">120.0</div>, <div class="lead-value">140.0</div>]
>>>blocks = soup.findall('div',{'class':'lead-value'}) 
>>>print blocks[1].string
100.0
```